# Show that if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in a vector space $E$ and $p\colon E\to\mathbb{R}$ with $p(x_n)\to0$, then $p(a_nx_n)\to 0$ . $a_n$ real and bound

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I found the following problem in Functional Analysis by Brezis.

> Let $E$ be a vector space and let $p\colon E\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with the following three properites:
> (i) $p(x+y)\leq p(x)+p(y)$.
> (ii) For each fixed $x\in E$, the function $\lambda\mapsto p(\lambda x)$ is continuous from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
> (iii) Whenever a sequences satisfies $p(y_n)\to 0$, then $p(\lambda y_n)\to 0$ for every $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$.
> Assume that $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $E$ such that $p(x_n)\to 0$ and $(\alpha_n)$ a bounded sequences in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $p(0)=0$ and that $p(a_nx_n)\to 0$.
> [**Hint:** Given $\varepsilon >0$, consider
> $$F_n=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\mid |p(\lambda x_k)|\leq \varepsilon,\; \forall k\geq n\}]$$

I have a partial proof but can't figue a way to continue:

Proving $p(0)=0$ is directo from the fact that $p(x_n)\to 0\implies p(0x_n)\to 0$. For the second claim, notice that
$$F_n=\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}\{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\mid |p(\lambda x_k)|\leq \varepsilon\}$$
and since $(p(\lambda x_k))_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}}$ is continuous for each $k$, $F_n$ is closed.
Since $p(\lambda x_n)\to 0$ for every $\lambda$, it is direct that
$$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} F_n=\mathbb{R}$$
and by the Baire Category Theorem, there exists a $m$ such that $\text{Int}(F_m)\neq \emptyset$. There exists then a $\omega\in \text{Int}(F_m)$ and a $\delta >0$ such that $(\omega-\delta,\omega+\delta)\subseteq \text{Int}(F_m)$.

---

I have no clue how to continue from here. I'm trying to somehow manipulate $\alpha_n$ so that it fits on the interval $(\omega-\delta,\omega+\delta)$ but not only am I failing but achieving this woudln't do much since $\delta$ depends on $\varepsilon$ so I would run into trouble.

I'm looking for any hints on how to continue.